# Independent symmetric 3-valued random variables in $L_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, random-variables, banach-spaces

Consider the following excerpt from [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3480):

> Given $1<p<2$, $0<w\leq 1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we fix once and for all a sequence $f_j^{(n)}=f_{p,w,j}^{(n)}$, $1\leq j\leq n$, of independent, symmetric, 3-valued random variables with $\|f_j^{(n)}\|_{L_p}=1$ and $\|f_j^{(n)}\|_{L_2}=\frac{1}{w}$ for $1\leq j\leq n$.  We then define $F_{p,w}^{(n)}$ to be the subspace $\text{span}\{f_j^{(n)}:1\leq j\leq n\}$ of $L_p$.  ...  Since the $f_j^{(n)}$ are 3-valued, $F_{p,w}^{(n)}$ is a subspace of the span of indicator functions of $3^n$ pairwise disjoint sets.  Thus, we can and will think of $F_{p,w}^{(n)}$ as a subspace of $\ell_p^{k_n}$, where $k_n=3^n$.

Two things about this, I don't understand.

**Question 1.**  How do we know that such $f_j^{(n)}$ exist?

**Question 2.**  I do not understand the last sentence above, about $F_{p,w}^{(n)}$ being viewed as a subspace of $\ell_p^{3^n}$.  Don't the pairwise disjoint sets they mention all need to have the same measure?  But this is impossible since the space $[0,1]$ has finite measure.  Otherwise, the embeddings will not be uniform.

EDIT:  $\|f_j^{(n)}\|_{L_p}=1$ means that $(\int_0^1|f_j^{(n)}(x)|^pdx)^{1/p}=1$, and $\|f_j^{(n)}\|_{L_2}=\frac{1}{w}$ means that $(\int_0^1|f_j^{(n)}(x)|^2dx)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{w}$.  I'm not sure what symmetric means in this context, but I *think* it means that $f_j^{(n)}(\frac{1}{2}-\delta)=f_j^{(n)}(\frac{1}{2}+\delta)$ for all $\delta\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: Is there a typo?  Why does it say $||f_j^{(n)}||_{L_p}=1$ and then immediately contradict this by saying $||f_j^{(n)}||_{L_p}=1/w$? Also, does $||f_j^{(n)}||_{L_p}=1$ mean that $E[|f_j^{(n)}|^p]=1$? And "symmetric" random variables means the mass function is symmetric about 0??  Clarifications would help.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the second norm should have been for $L_2$.  Fixed.  EDIT:  And I assume they are each symmetric about some value in $[0,1]$, since $L_p=L_p[0,1]$.

Comment: The definition of symmetric, and the assumption that the random variables take values in $[0,1]$, should be in the problem statement.

Comment: If $X \in [0,1]$ and $E[|X|^p]=1$, then $X=1$ with prob 1.

Answer (score 0):

A random variable $X$ is *symmetric* if for each Borel set $B$ we have $\mathsf{P}(X\in B) = \mathsf{P}(-X\in B)$.

Regarding your first question, we are looking for a measurable simple function $$f=-\mathbf{1}_{A_1} + 0\cdot \mathbf{1}_{A_2}+ \mathbf{1}_{A_3}$$ (once we have one, we have a sequence of independent copies) such that

- $\mu(A_1)=\mu(A_3)$
- $\mu(A_1)^p + \mu(A_3)^p = 1$
- $\sqrt{\mu(A_1)^2 + \mu(A_3)^2}=\frac{1}{w}$
- $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 = [0,1]$.

Can you solve this system of equations for Borel sets $A_1, A_2, A_3$ that are pair-wise disjoint?

The very idea of the proof relies on a theorem of Rosenthal which asserts that any sequence of independent 3-valued random variables in $L_p$ ($p\in (2,\infty)$) spans a complemented subspace of $L_p$ isomorphic to Rosenthal's space $X_p$; see his paper:

> H. P. Rosenthal, On the subspaces of $L_p$ ($p > 2$) spanned by sequences of
>   independent random variables. *Israel J. Math.* **8** (1970), 273–303.

No, the measures of supports need not be the same; the resulting finite-dimensional space you get is actually a [weighted $\ell_p^k$-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Weighted_Lp_spaces), hence (uniformly) isomorphic to $\ell_p^k$.